# how many distinct substrings of string A that don't contain string B as a substring

Tags: algorithm, knuth-morris-pratt

How can i use the KMP algorithm for finding the number of different substring of string A that don't contain string B as substring ?

I used KMP algorithm for some another problem but coudn't find how to solve this problem with KMP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show an example, please!

Comment: i used KMP for the number of occurrence of a string in another string, finding the minumum number of character which need to be added at the last of a string to make it palindrom etc.

Comment: for example string A="ababa" and string B="ba" , then there are 3 different substrings of A(they are "a", "b" and "ab") which dont contain B as a substring.

Comment: Please click on the edit link to add your example code to the question.

Comment: sorry, i haven't code yet. i'm stuck with the logic, maybe i shouldn't have tagged this with c++ .i'm sorry again

Answer (score 0):

I think KMP is the easy bit in a counting problem, where you need a pretty clear head. Using KMP you can go through the characters of A in turn, and detect characters of A which end an occurrence of B. You can use this to count the number of substrings of A which contain B.

If a character of A ends an occurrence of B, then every substring ending there which starts far enough back to contain B does in fact contain B. Substrings which are too short to contain B obviously don't. So in this case you can count the number of substrings of A ending at that character which contain B.

If a character of A does not end an occurrence of B, then every substring ending there which starts far enough back to contain a previous occurrence of B does in fact contain B. So (assuming that you remember where B was last seen) you can again count the number of substrings ending at this position which contain B.

So (in time linear in the length of A plus the length of B because counting the number of substrings ending at each position is just doing some simple arithmetic) you can count the number of substrings of A which contain B. Of course, you want the number of substrings that don't contain B, but the total number of substrings of A is just a quadratic in the length of A, so that is easy too.

Comment: can u please give me some links where i can learn about these kind of application of KMP. thanks again.

Comment: I'm afraid that I didn't write this answer from anything I have read, so I have nothing to refer you to. I just assumed that somebody had constructed what seemed to me a rather artificial problem by wrapping the use of KMP in what they probably called an elementary mathematical puzzle. Furthermore, I haven't used any sophisticated property of KMP, except that it find patterns cheaply in the worst case. I have a vague acquaintance with combinatorics, which might have helped, though I can't claim to be familar with the subject - in fact it would probably cross the street to avoid me :-)